# Запуск новой сессии

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, сессия

Я работаю с сессиями первый раз, и у меня возникла потребность в определённый момент создать и запустить сессию. Делаю сайт на ASP MVC, хочу сделать авторизацию, и чтоб после успешной авторизации запускалась сессия пользователя. Но, если пользователь бездействует, и проходит время указанное  timeout сессия удалялась, а пользователя перебрасывало на страницу авторизации.
Можно ли как-то создать эту сессию в определённый момент, и отследить её начало и конец жизненного цикла через события Session_Start , Session_End?

Comment: [Управление сеансами и состояниями в ASP.NET Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.timeout?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: @tym32167, это я уже сделал. Она запускается с запуском программы, и я могу отследить её жизненный цикл по событиям. Но меня интересует, как можно либо запустить её после успешной авторизации на сайте, либо перезапустить после повторной авторизации на сайте, после того как пользователь вышел из учётной записи, либо сессия была закончена из-за бездействия.

Comment: По идее сессия юзера начинается когда он открывает ваш сайт в браузере. Я уже деталей не помню, но вроде идентификаторы сессии передаются через состояние, типа через куки или viewstate. Когда юзер авторизуется, у него в этот момент уже есть сессия, ничего не надо запускать.